# Api de Traefik con docker-compose ¿Cómo activar la api de Traefik v2.1?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik2

estoy montando un sitio web con docker y traefik, en el proyecto tengo 5 contenedores.

```
Traefik
Wordpress
mysql
nginx
phpmyadmin
```

cuando ejecuto el comando `docker-compose up -d` todos los contenedores se levantan sin ningun problema, sin embargo tengo activada la api de traefik pero no logro entrar al dashboard ya que me arroja un `error 404`.

este es mi archivo `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    container_name: traefik
    labels: 
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=8080
    ports: 
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes: 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - web

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.port=3306
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - web

  wp:
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: wp
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.rule=Host(`midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=9000
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}"
    networks:
      - web
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: wp-nginx
    depends_on: 
      - wp
    labels: 
      - traefik.port=80
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./conf.d/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - web

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: ${PMA_HOST}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`pa.midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=80
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    driver: "bridge"
```

y este es mi archivo `traefik.yml`

```
# DEFINE EL PROVEEDOR DOCKER
providers:
    docker:
        endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

api:
    dashboard: true
    debug: true

# DEFINE LOS PUNTOS DE ENTRADA DE TRAEFIK
entryPoints:
    web:
        address: ":80"
    websecure:
        address: ":443"
    dashboard:
        address: ":8080"

# REDIRIGE LAS PETICIONES HTTP A HTTPS
http:
    routers:
        router0:
            rule: "Host(`midominio.com`)"
            entryPoints:
                - web
            middlewares:
                - https_redirect
            service: wp

# GENERA CERTIFICADOS SSL PARA LOS CONTENEDORES DE DOCKER
certificatesResolvers:
    myresolver:
        acme:
            email: correo@email.cl
            storage: ./letsencrypt/acme.json
            httpChallenge:
                entryPoint: web

# MIDDLEWARES GLOBALES DE TRAEFIK
middlewares:
    https_redirect:
        redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true
```

así lucen mis contenedores:

```
db           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp                                                        
phpmyadmin   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up      80/tcp                                                          
traefik      /entrypoint.sh traefik           Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
wp           docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up      80/tcp, 9000/tcp                                                
wp-nginx     /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      80/tcp
```

Este es el log de traefik.

```
traefik          | time="2020-07-24T15:40:31Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: /traefik.yml"
```

estoy utilizando `traefik en su versiòn 2.1`, he visto la documentaciòn pero no logro activar la api, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba a poner dentro de una label lo siguiente:

 - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"

Para acceder de forma segura al panel necesitas la API. Y esto otro, en teoría podría no hacer falta pero me he contrado algún caso en el que no he podido acceder sin la etiqueta  "traefik.enable=true".

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en versiones anteriores como por ej: la 1.7 de traefik, para activar el dashboard de la api basta con agregar en el archivo toml [api] entyponts: "dashboard", entonces como me cambie a la versiòn 2.1, sólo se debe agregar el label que me indicas "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal" y todo funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, saludos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para los que andan buscando esta respuesta, lo he solucionado agregando el label

```
"traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
```

Espero les ayude, saludos :)